# Import SMS messages from Samsung .nef file to Sony Xperia S

Tags: sms, samsung, import, sony-xperia-s

How can I import my SMS message from a Samsung phone to a Sony one?

New PS Studio gave me a `.nef` file that I can't import to my Sony phone.

Comment: I have a new Sony Experia x10, and would like to import my backed-up sms's from my Samsung S4. The Sony PC Companion does not recognise the Samsung files. Samsung has a BK extention and Sony DBK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en) assuming those are both Android phones and you shouldn't need to deal with a `.nef` file.

Answer (score 1):

The `.nef` file is actually a normal database, which can be opened (and exported, and edited and ...) by Microsoft Access. The only thing is that it has an unrecognizable extension. Rename the file to `xxxx.mdb`, and you can open it in Microsoft Access by double-clicking it.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359323/open-a-standard-jet-db-4-0-file-vmd